# Persistent invalid syntax error from pylint

Tags: python

I've been getting a persistent invalid syntax error from pylint in my code, and I can't figure it out. I've double and triple-checked that I don't have any unclosed parentheses, and I still can't figure it out. I did something(I'm not sure what) that moved it down from where it originally was(around line 90) down to where it currently is(line 117).

Another thing that's confusing me is that the error is on the first space of an indented line. Does that give a clue as to what could be causing it? I'll post all my code below.

Edit:Thank you for explaining how to format the code correctly in post

```
import sys
import pydub
import pylab
import os
import math
import wave
import struct

def goertzel(samples):
    """
    Implementation of the Goertzel algorithm, useful for calculating individual
    terms of a discrete Fourier transform.

    `samples` is a windowed one-dimensional signal originally sampled at `sample_rate`.

    The function returns 2 arrays, one containing the actual frequencies calculated,
    the second the coefficients `(real part, imag part, power)` for each of those frequencies.
    For simple spectral analysis, the power is usually enough.

    Example of usage :

        freqs, results = goertzel(some_samples, 44100, (400, 500), (1000, 1100))
    """
    # We will only be processing audio, so 48kHz is the sample rate we will use.
    # Likewise, since we will only be doing DTMF decoding, we can hard code the
    # frequencies we look for. We take both of these out of the argument list for
    # the algorithm.
    # -Maudrie
    SAMPLE_RATE=48000
    freqs=((697, 770, 852, 941, 1209, 1336, 1477))
    window_size = len(samples)
    f_step = SAMPLE_RATE / float(window_size)
    f_step_normalized = 1.0 / window_size

    # Calculate all the DFT bins we have to compute to include frequencies
    # in `freqs`.
    bins = set()
    for f_range in freqs:
        f_start, f_end = f_range
        k_start = int(math.floor(f_start / f_step))
        k_end = int(math.ceil(f_end / f_step))

        if k_end > window_size - 1: raise ValueError('frequency out of range %s' % k_end)
        bins = bins.union(range(k_start, k_end))

    # For all the bins, calculate the DFT term
    n_range = range(0, window_size)
    freqs = []
    results = []
    for k in bins:

        # Bin frequency and coefficients for the computation
        f = k * f_step_normalized
        w_real = 2.0 * math.cos(2.0 * math.pi * f)
        w_imag = math.sin(2.0 * math.pi * f)

        # Doing the calculation on the whole sample
        d1, d2 = 0.0, 0.0
        for n in n_range:
            y  = samples[n] + w_real * d1 - d2
            d2, d1 = d1, y

        # Storing results `(real part, imag part, power)`
        #We don't need real part or imag part, we only need power
        #-Maudrie
        results.append(d2**2 + d1**2 - w_real * d1 * d2)
        freqs.append(f * sample_rate)
    return freqs, results

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if (len(sys.argv)>=2):
        inputaudio=sys.argv[2]
    else :
        print("Specify file path as command line arg")

    with contextlib.closing(wave.open(inputaudio,'r')) as f:
        frames = f.getnframes()
        rate = f.getframerate()
        duration = frames / float(rate)
        chunk_no=ceil(duration/.04)

    outputstring=""

    for x in range (chunk_no):

        t1=x*.4
        t2=t1+.4
        if (t2>duration):t2=duration

        chunk=AudioSegment.from_wav(inputaudio)
        chunk=chunk[t1:t2]
        chunk.export('chunk.wav', format="wav")
        meas_freqs, result= goertzel('chunk.wav')

        meas_freq1, meas_freq2=find_two_most_present(meas_freqs, result)

        actual_freq1=find_most_similar(meas_freq1)
        actual_freq2=find_most_similar(meas_freq2)

        if actual_freq1>actual_freq2:
            actual_freq1, actual_freq2= actual_freq2, actual_freq1

        outputstring=outputstring+dtmf_to_digit(actual_freq1, actual_freq2)

        os.remove('chunk.wav')

    print(outputstring)

def find_two_most_present(meas_freqs, result):

    highest=0
    second=0
    highest_index=-1
    second_index=-1
    #line 116; pylint only highlights the first space of the next line
    for y in range len(result):
        if result[y]>second:
            if result[y]>highest:
                highest=result[y]
            else:
                second=result[y]

    return meas_freqs[highest_index], meas_freqs[second_index]

def dtmf_to_digit(x,y):
    if x==697:
        if y==1209:
            return "1"
        elif y==1336:
            return "2"
        else:
            return "3"
    elif x==770:
        if y==1209:
            return "4"
        elif y==1336:
            return "5"
        else:
            return "6"
    elif x==852:
        if y==1209:
            return "7"
        elif y==1336:
            return "8"
        else:
            return "9"
    else:
        if y==1209:
            return "*"
        elif y==1336:
            return "0"
        else:
            return "#"

def find_most_similar(meas_freq):

    dmtf_freqs=[697, 770, 852, 941, 1209, 1336, 1477]

    error=10000
    most_similar_index=-1
    for x in len(dtmf_freqs):
        new_error=abs((dtmf_freqs[x]-meas_freq)/meas_freq)
        if (new_error<error):
            error, most_similar_index=new_error,x

    return dtmf_freqs[most_similar_index]
```

Comment: For formatting: Select your code, then click the `{}` button (or press Ctrl-K).

Comment: What is `range len(result)`?

Comment: len(result) is the length of the array result, so for y in range len(result) should iterate through the array (0 to len(result)-1)

Comment: Show us the error message.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure `range len` is a syntax error.

Comment: I guess you're right, I was misusing range. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`range()` is a function in Python. It looks like you're using it as a statement.

Line 117 should be:

```
for y in range(len(result)):
```

It looks like you're intending to find the index of the highest and the second highest, but `highest_index` and `second_index` are always `-1`.

Comment: This works, and also for y in len(result): seems to work. I don't know how I got range wrong in my head.

Comment: FWIW, that function has a bug where it wont' find the second highest value. The second highest just gets set to the last value that wasn't greater than the highest.

Comment: While typing out my response to you asking why that is, I worked it out. So what I should do is, when a value is found to be greater than the highest, I need to simultaneously assign second=highest. Thanks for pointing that out to me!

Comment: @SaltyCrusader Good job! Good luck with your project.